# How to build libjpeg.lib for using it with ijg jpeg library?

Tags: c++, image, boost, boost-gil

I want to read jpeg images for my program, which uses GIL (a Boost library). In the documentation for GIL, it is recommended to use the jpeg library present at http://www.ijg.org/. Among other things, it is also required to compile and link against *libjpeg.lib* for making it work.

This is where I ran into a problem.

There is no *libjpeg.lib* file available.

I read the documentation( install.txt and libjpeg.txt ) of the ijg jpeg library, and got hinted that I will have to somehow build it myself. But so far, I have been unable to do so.

The documentation says," The most convenient way to include the JPEG code into your executable program is to prepare a library file ("*libjpeg.a*", or a corresponding name on non-Unix machines) and reference it at your link step. The supplied makefiles build libjpeg.a automatically".

However, when I tried to build it using command line of Visual Studio 2010, it generated a bunch of other files, but not *libjpeg.lib*.

I searched a lot on Google, and tried several solutions, to no avail.

I even got a *libjpeg.lib* file while searching, but including it gives another error - "cannot open *libc.lib*".

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (native C++) on Windows 7.

I have spent the past four days trying to make it work. Can someone of you knowledgable folks help me?

**EDIT:** I have got the answer to my question on my own. I have posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer to my own question. Actually, the supplied makefiles *do* build a .lib file, but it is named jpeg.lib, and NOT libjpeg.lib.

The following video explains the process of building the required library: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YirxxtFpJIU.

Also, the following tutorial is helpful: http://www.dahlsys.com/misc/compiling_ijg_libjpeg/index.html. It also states how to use the library (in case you do not already know).

Also, add the name of the library ('jpeg.lib') to Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.